# Feign ErrorDecoder is not invoked - how to configure feign to use it?

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

As i understand the decode() method of the feign ErrorDecoder will be called when a request responds with a status code != 2xx. Through debugging my tests i found out that the decode() method of my CustomErrorDecoder is not invoked on e.g. 504 or 404. I tried two ways to configure it:

Either include it as a Bean in the client configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public CustomErrorDecoder customErrorDecoder() {
        return new CustomErrorDecoder();
    }
```

or write it into the application configuration :

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      myCustomRestClientName:
        retryer: com.a.b.some.package.CustomRetryer
        errorDecoder: com.a.b.some.package.CustomErrorDecoder
```

Both ways don't invoke the ErrorDecoder. What am I doing wrong? The Bean is beeing instantiated and my CustomErrorDecoder looks like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String s, Response response) {
        Exception exception = defaultErrorDecoder.decode(s, response);

        if (exception instanceof RetryableException) {
            return exception;
        }

        if (response.status() == 504) {
            // throwing new RetryableException to retry 504s
        }
        return exception;
    }
}
```

---

### Update:

I have created  a minimal reproducible example in <del>this git repo</del>. Please look at the commit history to find 3 ways that I tried.

Comment: Everything in the question seems to be ok. Could you please share [example]? Probably a mistake is somewhere else...

Comment: @amseager I've updated the question to include a link to the git repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your feign client uses `feign.Response` as the return type:

```
import feign.Param;
import feign.RequestLine;
import feign.Response;

public interface TestEngineRestClient {

    @RequestLine(value = "GET /{uuid}")
    Response getReport(@Param("uuid") String uuid);
}
```

In this case, Feign delegates its handling to the developer - e.g., you can retrieve HTTP status and a response body and do some stuff with it.

*If interested, you can look at the source code of `feign.SynchronousMethodHandler`, `executeAndDecode` section.*

To fix this, replace `Response.class` with the desired type in case of the correct response with status code = 2xx (probably some DTO class). I made a [PR](https://github.com/dnl-re/feign-error-decoder-problem/pull/1/files) where I've changed it to `String` for simplicity.